# DART - Resize div element event

Tags: dart

I am using CSS3 `resize: vertical;` to allow the user to resize a Div, and would like to be notified when this happens (so that I can adjust the size of other elements with Dart code if necessary).

How can I attach an event listener for the user resize event?
( `DivElement.on.resize` does not exist.)

Comment: The browser does not fire resize events, unfortunately. So this is not possible in Dart nor JavaScript, at least not without some tricks (like listening to mouse presses and keeping the size of the input in memory for later comparison, etc.)

Comment: That seems to contradict:  [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp): "The onresize event is supported in all major browsers. ... onresize is Supported by the Following HTML Tags:  <a>, <address>, <b>, <big>, <blockquote>, <body>, <button>, <cite>, <code>, <dd>, <dfn>, **<div>**..."

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about this specific scenario. The resize event does not fire for textarea (at least not on Chrome).

Comment: Thanks Kai.  I see what you are saying (even though it was a Div, not Textarea I was talking about).  Presumably the browsers will implement this in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to observe event which is not listed under the `on` getter, you can use [`$dom_addEventListener`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Element.html#%24dom_addEventListener) to set event listener.

Thus, if you would like to use something like the unexisting `divElement.on.resize`, you can use :

```dart
divElement.$dom_addEventListener("resize", (e) {
  // event occurs
});
```

That said, unlike `click` event, the `resize` event doesn't seem to be fired (even in *javascript*).